# How do I copy a control between forms and still maintain child controls?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Let's say I have a `TabStrip` control, and I have `two Tabs`: one with a `WebBrowser`, and one with a `Textbox`. I want to **copy** this to another `Form`, so that it **docks** to that `Form`, but I can't.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which control you want to copy? Is it everything (TabStrip, webbrowser, textbox) or particular control only like Textbox only? By the way show any code that you have come up so far.

Comment: You can't, controls are not copyable.  Toolstrips are created in code.  Normally that code is in the InitializeComponent() method.  Sounds like you want to call this code more than once.  So move that code into a method that returns a ToolStrip object.

Answer (score 0):

in the form you want to copy the control to try this:

```
    Dim tc As New TabControl
    tc = New Form1().TabControl
    Me.Controls.Add(tc)
```

The tabcontrol should be copied to the other form with all the properties intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the form code file and rename the copy and rename the form class name 
this way you will have all the controls and properties exactly the same